# Formatting string for readability and printing

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to format the string below with variables for readability, I would like to break it up so it easier read, right now it takes up 199 characters in the script line, every attempt I make seems to break it up so when printed it has large gaps, can anyone shed some light?  I tried wrapping it in """ triple quotes and \ at the end but it still has spaces when printed or logged.

```
 copy_sql = "COPY {0} FROM 's3://{1}/{2}' CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id={3};aws_secret_access_key={4}' {5}; ".format(table_name,bucket,key,aws_access_key_id,aws_secret_access_key,options)
```

Desired result would be something to this affect:

```
    copy_sql = "COPY {0} FROM 's3://{1}/{2}' \
                CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id={3};aws_secret_access_key={4}' {5}; \
               ".format(table_name,bucket,key, \
               aws_access_key_id,aws_secret_access_key,options)
```

However when I print it I get large spaces between .gz and credentials:

```
COPY analytics.table FROM 's3://redshift-fake/storage/2017-11-02/part-00000.gz'                         CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=SECRET;aws_secret_access_key=SECRET' DELIMITER '\t'  dateformat 'auto' fillrecord removequotes gzip;
```

I am thinking this would still work but I would like to clean it up for logging readability.

Comment: Just put "CREDETIALS" to begin of the line

Comment: That works but it still is ugly, I would like to keep it very clean if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [string literal concatenation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literal-concatenation):

> Multiple adjacent string literals (delimited by whitespace), possibly using different quoting conventions, are allowed, and their meaning is the same as their concatenation. Thus, `"hello" 'world'` is equivalent to `"helloworld"`.

In your case, something like this:

```
copy_sql = ("COPY {0} FROM 's3://{1}/{2}' "
            "CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id={3};aws_secret_access_key={4}' {5};"
           ).format(table_name,bucket,key,
                   aws_access_key_id,aws_secret_access_key,options)
```

Note the extra parentheses to make it parse correctly. As long as a line ending is inside at least one pair of parenthes, Python will always treat it as a line continuation, without the need for backslashes.

Comment: Thank you very much for linking to the documentation and providing the example, this was exactly what I was looking for.